# arduino array to int value

Tags: arrays, string, arduino

I am working on a arduino ,
I have array

```
int remotvalue[] ={5,7,8,3};
```

I want to join all of the value of remotevalue[] array,
like
`int result =5783;`

can this is possible in arduino .?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is less of an arduino specific question and more of a general programming question. Arduino runs C so any solution that would work in C would work for you here. For example:

```
int result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   result += remotValue[3-i] * pow(10, i);
}
```

Comment: It's actually C++ (currently C++11), and using `pow` on the `AVR` architecture is extremely slow (as the floats are emulated).

Comment: `int res = 0; for (int& x : remotvalue) res = res*10 + x;` would do much better job.. (and it'd be even better (and faster) by using int8_t for the array and `x`)